# Google Cloud vision: namespace Google\Cloud\Samples\Vision error 500

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I'm using Google Cloud vision for text detection.

Below you can find the code I'm using following google instructions.
The strange thing is that if i Comment the namespace line (namespace Google\Cloud\Samples\Vision;) I receive the text output. If it's uncommented I receive an error 500. How to sort it out?

My final expectation is to have text result in a more structured way, like a json or an array.
Is this possible?

```
    require "vendor/autoload.php";
    putenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=".$abs_path."path/to/myjson.json");
      use Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient;
      namespace Google\Cloud\Samples\Vision;
      $path = "path/to/myimage.png";
      detect_text($path);
      function detect_text($path)
      {
      $imageAnnotator = new ImageAnnotatorClient();

      # annotate the image
      $image = file_get_contents($path);
      $response = $imageAnnotator->textDetection($image);
      $texts = $response->getTextAnnotations();

      printf('%d texts found:' . PHP_EOL, count($texts));
      foreach ($texts as $text) {
          print($text->getDescription() . PHP_EOL);
      }

      $imageAnnotator->close();
  }
```

Comment: Could you please share the text output you mentioned you are receiving and the full 500 error.

Comment: Also, the results are structured in a json as is mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#text_detection_requests) ,  so your last comment is not clear

Comment: with namespace commented I receive this text "21 texts found: EXECUTIVE OFFICE OF THE PRESIDENT OFFICE OF MANAGEMENT AND BUDGET STATISTICAL PROGRAMS OF THE UNITED STATES GOVERNMENT FISCAL YEAR 2017 EXECUTIVE OFFICE OF THE PRESIDENT OFFICE OF MANAGEMENT AND BUDGET STATISTICAL PROGRAMS OF THE UNITED STATES GOVERNMENT FISCAL YEAR 2017" for this path  $path = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3c/Statistical-programs-2017.pdf/page1-320px-Statistical-programs-2017.pdf.jpg"

Comment: About the error, I sorted it out: The error was: Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script

Comment: About the output I receive, with the foreach statement, a line with full text and then a line for each single word. Is this the expected output?

Comment: Glad to know that you fixed the error. As for the format of output received, it's all based on the Vision API OCR model and how it detects the text within the image. Testing your same image on https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/drag-and-drop, the output came in 4 blocks; block 1 with 3 paragraphs, block 2 with 2 paragraphs and block 3 with 1, along with 4 with only 1 word detected. Let me know if this helps